# Which Faces to choose

Tags: jsf

I am on the hunt for a extra component library to the core JSF 2.0 library. I need calender-pick, tabbed pane, tree view and other nice components to complete my Java EE 6 - Glassfish 3 project.

But I don't know which additional library to choose; MyFaces, OpenFaces, PrimeFaces, etc. I never tried any of them.

My most important requirement for the additional library I choose, is the footprint in bandwidth and memory it will make. It has the be a lightweight library, because the web-system is used by many users in the developing countries, where bandwidth is far from what we have in US/Europe. Plus it would be nice if there is some RAID editor tool for the web-designers people to use when designing the View/GUI part. Thought of Dreamweaver, but I don't know if it can render the components (JSF core and Faces libs)?

What additional Faces library do recommend me to choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) seems suitable option. You can use JBoss Tools (Free) as WYSIWYG IDE. It is being actively developed and maintained. The new version 4, will work even better with JSF2.
To conserve bandwidth you may need to look at compression techniques on static resources.

Comment: Yes, compression is useful. I guess it uses compression by default ? So I can Glassfish and RichFaces, I'll look into it ?

Comment: What's the name of the WYSIWYG IDE and where can I find it ?

Comment: The name of IDE is JBoss Tools. You can get it at - http://www.jboss.org/tools You'll also need to add richfaces plugin.

Comment: I am using Netbeans, guess there is no plug-in for that. Is RichFaces open-source ?

Comment: How is OpenFaces, seams light and has the components that I am looking for?

Comment: The last time I tried OpenFaces, it was in beta state. Maybe you could try it as proof-of-concept? 
RichFaces is opensource